# Studio 2.2 has an android-19 x86 system image that runs with Qemu2 and the ranchu hardware - how was it built?

Tags: android-emulator, android-source, qemu

I am attempting to build a 5.1 x86 Emulator "System Image" that can be used by the latest Android Emulator, which uses a much newer Qemu code base, and has fewer problems with network bridging (for example). But I've run into a real mystery, the answer to which might explain why this task is giving me so much trouble. So first, a little back-story...

Android-19 (KitKat, ~4.4) used an ancient version of Qemu as the base for its emulator. The Android team subsequently announced that they were moving to "Qemu2", a newer/better code base, and its first use would be to support arm64 emulation, using a new emulator hardware definition called "ranchu". This did ship in Lollipop (~5.x, android-20-22), and unfortunately the x86 support was in fact omitted.

But here's the mystery - when you run the 4.4/KitKat x86 system image that is in Studio 2.2/Build Tools 25.0.2 with the -verbose flag, you can see that it is using the *new* Qemu, as well as the "ranchu" hardware definition and kernel:

```
    Concatenated QEMU options:
 /Users/xx
 xx/.android-sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
 -dns-server 10.11.11.11,10.11.11.14 -serial null -cpu android32
 -enable-hax -smp cores=2 -m 1536 -lcd-density 320 -kernel /Users/xx
 xx/.android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/x86//kernel-ranchu
 -initrd /Users/xx
 xx/.android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/x86//ramdisk.img
 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -drive
 if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=0,id=system,file=/Users/xx
 xx/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_19.avd/system.img.qcow2,read-only
 -device
 virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
 -drive
 if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=1,id=cache,file=/Users/xx
 xx/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_19.avd/cache.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576
 -device
 virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
 -drive
 if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=2,id=userdata,file=/Users/xx
 xx/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_19.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576
 -device
 virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
 -drive
 if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=3,id=sdcard,file=/Users/xx
 xx/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_19.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576
 -device
 virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify
 -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -netdev
 user,id=mynet2,net=10.0.3.0/24 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet2
 -show-cursor -L /Users/xx xx/.android-sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios
 -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu
 clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0
 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 ndns=2' -android-hw /Users/xx
 xx/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_19.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
```

So my question is - how was this system image created? The facts imply that an entirely different build system put it together. The code that would create a 4.4 system.img file that supported ranchu doesn't exist in the aosp 4.4 branch! And while it does exist in the 5.1 branch, it only supports arm64. So - is there anyone out there that can explain what up here?